# How can I recompile and update javascript in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the past I have used the "sources" tab within Chrome Dev Tools to edit the javascript of a web page (which I have since forgotten how to do).
I remember clicking something like `ctrl + s`?, this would cause *only the javascript* of the webpage to be re-interpreted by the browser.
This message would appear in the console

> Recompilation and update succeeded

This would allow local changes to the javascript that could be tested and  discarded once the entire page was loaded, i.e. the same as you could do with CSS or HTML.

From memory there was a couple of steps that had to be taken before it worked, e.g. it would only work if maybe there was a `debug` statement in the javascript and the source tab had to be open or something?

Ive tried

- The [dev tools documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs)
- similar SO questions, but they havent explained the **entire** process or they are inconsistent from one anser to the next
- Looking at the keymaps in the chrome dev tools itself

Can someone explain the steps necessary to **recompile and update** javascript in chrome dev tools?

- Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit)
- OS Ubuntu 14.04